# Combine two arrays to filter a common result?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, filter

I have two arrays -  the actual array has 2500 entries, now showing few for sample ). I have implemented a realtime search functionality in react native. This is my function,

By this, when user types anything it filters and displays in flatlist ! It works perfectly, but the thing is i have another array2 in which it has alias name for the cities in array1 ( note: not every cities have alias names ). My question is how to combine both to filter,

For example : when user types "Tiruchirapalli" or "Trichy" it should show alias name and for the cities which doesn't have alias its original name should be shown !

How to achieve this ?

Array1

```js
const array1 = [{
    "id": "117",
    "name": "Tiruchirapalli",
    "stateId": "101"
  },
  {
    "id": "27110",
    "name": "Ganoda",
    "stateId": "1405"
  },
  {
    "id": "203",
    "name": "Tenkasi",
    "stateId": "101"
  },
  {
    "id": "115",
    "name": "Thanjavur",
    "stateId": "101"
  },
];
```

Array2

```
const array2 = [{
    "id": 1850,
    "cityName": "Tenkasi",
    "aliasNames": [
      "Thenkasi"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 4521,
    "cityName": "Tiruchirapalli",
    "aliasNames": [
      "Trichy"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 115,
    "cityName": "Thanjavur",
    "aliasNames": [
      "Tanjore"
    ]
  },
];
```

Attempt

```
searchFilterFunction = text => {
  this.setState({
    typedText: text
  });
  const newData = this.arrayholder.filter(item => {
    const itemData = `${item.name.toUpperCase()}`;
    const textData = text.toUpperCase();
    return itemData.indexOf(textData) > -1;
  });
  this.setState({
    data: newData
  });
};
```

Comment: I tried to make a snippet, but it is React and incorrect so I just formatted

Comment: If possible kindly provide a solution ! @mplungjan

Comment: No, the thing is that i have two separate array, i couldn't understand how to combine both and produce single result

Answer (score 0):

Just an example, I think you're on the right track.
I didn't define otherIndex but I think you get the idea:

```
searchFilterFunction = text => {
  this.setState({
    typedText: text
  });
  const newData = this.arrayholder.filter(item => {
    const itemData = `${item.name.toUpperCase()}`;
    const textData = text.toUpperCase();
    const index = itemData.indexOf(textData) > -1
    return index ? array2[index] : array1[otherIndex]
  });
  this.setState({
    data: newData
  });
};
```

Comment: But the arrayholder only contains array1 datas, it doesnt have array2 datas ( its in separate variable )

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve without combining them and searching individually. And I assume you need to show alias if exists and show name only when alias is not present

```
searchFilterFunction = text => {
      this.setState({
        typedText: text
      });
      
       // Assuming you need to show alias if exists and show name only when alias 
       // is not present
      let newData = this.arrayholder2.find(item => {
        const textData = text.toUpperCase();
        return itemD.aliasNames.filter(alias => 
              alias.toUpperCase().includes(textData)).length > 0;
      });

      if(newData === undefined) {
        // alias does not match, search name now
         newData = this.arrayholder1.find(item => {
           const itemData = `${item.name.toUpperCase()}`;
           const textData = text.toUpperCase();
           return itemData.includes(textData);
        });
      }

      this.setState({
        data: newData
      });
    };
```

Comment: "aliasNames" are in different arrayholder ? I could understand the logic behind those two array filter implementation ? Can you explain it ?

Comment: Edited my code now, find the alias by first find where in aliasName is array so using filter and condition is typedText should be present with in alias name (substring)

Comment: No its not working, it just throws error as undefined on  "item.name.toUpperCase()"

Comment: Kindly put your sample code in jsdfiddle or somehere and share the link here so that people can see and help

Answer (score 0):

In function, first build an object from aliases array, Where key is `cityName` and value is `aliases`.

Now, in the first array filter method, Check for `text` match in both in `name` and corresponding aliases array using `some` method.

```js
const filtered = (data, aliasArr, text) => {
  const aliases = {};
  aliasArr.forEach(
    ({ cityName, aliasNames }) => (aliases[cityName] = aliasNames)
  );

  return data.filter(({ name }) => {
    return name.toUpperCase().includes(text.toUpperCase()) ||
      aliases[name]?.some((alias) =>
        alias.toUpperCase().includes(text.toUpperCase())
      );
  });
};

const array1 = [
  {
    id: "117",
    name: "Tiruchirapalli",
    stateId: "101",
  },
  {
    id: "27110",
    name: "Ganoda",
    stateId: "1405",
  },
  {
    id: "203",
    name: "Tenkasi",
    stateId: "101",
  },
  {
    id: "115",
    name: "Thanjavur",
    stateId: "101",
  },
];

const array2 = [
  {
    id: 1850,
    cityName: "Tenkasi",
    aliasNames: ["Thenkasi"],
  },
  {
    id: 4521,
    cityName: "Tiruchirapalli",
    aliasNames: ["Trichy"],
  },
  {
    id: 115,
    cityName: "Thanjavur",
    aliasNames: ["Tanjore"],
  },
];

console.log(filtered(array1, array2, 'Th'))
```